# Different version of graph isomorphism between two directed graph

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

**Background**

We are given two directed graphs that can have cycles in them, let's call them $G_1$ and $G_2$, where we have a restriction function $(\mid)$ that takes $G_1$ and an argument and returns a restricted graph such that it's isomorphic to $G_2$. For instance, the restricted $G_1 | X$ and $G_X$ are isomorphic.

**Example**

For example, vertices of $G_1$ are of this form: $X.a$, $X.b$ and $Y.a$ and $Y.b$ and vertices of $G_2$ are of this form: $a$ and $b$ so if we "restrict" the $G_1$ graph by $X$ we get a new graph that has only vertice that starts with $X$ and remove the prefix, we get vertices that match vertices in $G_2$

**What we want to prove**

Now we want to prove that if we apply transitive closure on $G_1$ then its restricted form is still isomorphic to $G_2$.

**Is it a graph isomorphism problem?**

The [formal definition of graph isomorphism says that we must guess the function that maps the vertices between two graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4296588/49780) but this function is known to us (we just need to restrict the vertice by filtering out the vertices that start with the parameter and and removing the prefix, see above example):

> $G,H$ are isomorphic if there is a bijection $f: V(G) \to V(H)$ such that a directed edge $(u,v)$ exists in $G$ if and only if the edge $(f(u), f(v))$ exists in $H$.

---

So I need some help or hints on how to prove this. Thank you.

Comment: The thing you want to prove shouldn't be true in general. If $G|X$ is isomorphic to $G_2$ and taking the transitive closure of $G$ gives a graph $T(G)$ which adds new edges between the vertices with an $X$ prefix, then $T(G)|X$ will no longer be isomorphic to $G_2$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov what if we assume $G_2$ has already gone through transitive closures? so it shouldn't need any new edges.

Comment: Even then, it seems possible that the other structure of $G$ adds new edges to $G|X$. In your example, if $G$ has vertices $\{X.a, X.b, Y.a, Y.b\}$ with edges $(X.a,Y.a)$ and $(Y.a,X.b)$, and $G_2$ has vertices $\{a,b\}$ with no edges, then $G_2$ is transitively closed. But the transitive closure of $G$ adds the edge $(X.a,X.b)$, ruining the isomorphism between $G|X$ and $G_2$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov makes sense. Sorry, I am asking too many questions. Under what conditions they two graphs might be isomorphic to each other?

Comment: I think that's the wrong question to ask. Situations where $T(G)|X$ is still isomorphic to $G_2$ (equivalent, $T(G)|X$ has the same edge set as $G|X$) are rare; sufficient conditions someone might come up with are not likely to be helpful to you. Instead, think about special properties of your specific problem that might be useful. (For example, you used the group-isomorphism tag; do these graphs come from some sort of group structure that could be used here?)